# Jquery-ui Datepicker not showing in rails view, got error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Datepicker from jquery-ui doesn't show up in my view.

application.js

```
require('jquery');
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker");
```

environment.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: 'jquery/src/jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
})
)

environment.toWebpackConfig().merge({
resolve: {
alias: {
'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery'
}
}
});
```

in my view

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#reservation_start_date').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
      $('#reservation_end_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
  });

</script>
```

Chrome Console

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Thank u everyone for helping!

SOLVED doing this:
We have to expose jQuery to the window object :

## packs/application.js

```
import JQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.JQuery = JQuery;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yarn add jquery-ui-dist` then add `'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'` inside your `alias` method.

configure your `environment.js` properly. `$` and `jQuery` should be a `jquery` not path to jquery. see following changes.
 you don't need `require('jquery');` in `application.js`

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: "jquery",
jQuery: "jquery",
Popper: ["popper.js", "default"]
})

environment.toWebpackConfig().merge({
resolve: {
alias: {
'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
}
}
});
```

Comment: Thank u!But looks like i have some sort of conflict with jquery. I got same error with every datetime script i try, jqueri-.ui, flatpicker, bootstrap datetime

Comment: Thanks again. So i solved doing this, just have to expose jquery to the window object, in  # packs/application.js

import JQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.JQuery = JQuery;